# Testing voltage continuity using a beeper?

Tags: voltage, oscillator

I have a 48v rail and i wish to plug it into an audible oscillator to check for continuity when i am rattling the system under duress. What is the simplest circuit that i can plug into 48v to hear the voltage accurately?

I want an always on buzzer that makes a sound when it is running on 48v and that stops if the current is briefly interrupted.

Comment: The one you can buy off-the-shelf..

Comment: Your question is confusing. Do you want the circuit to beep when it is at 48V or to do a continuity check between two points of the circuit while it is running. Please give a more accurate description of the circuit and application

Comment: I checked buzzers on digikey and they are all short/long signals, I  couldnt find a continuous one?
I want an always on buzzer that makes a sound when it is running on 48v and that stops if the current is briefly interrupted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest I can think of would use a relay, push-button switch and a buzzer.  If you can't find a suitable 48V relay and buzzer, you may need a voltage regulator.

Push SW1 to start the buzzer.  That will latch the relay on, unless the voltage drops out.  Then the buzzer will stop until you re-start it with SW1 again.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fNw6mG.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Don't forget to use a buzzer, not a speaker!

Comment: @user1582568 I couldn't find buzzer on the list of circuit symbols.  Assume that SPKR1 is a suitable buzzer (perhaps with a voltage-dropper resistor or voltage regulator if required).